# How can I headshot while jumping?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

With all the random bullets in CS GO, I really don't see how some people consistently do jump headshots while firing only once.

Can someone please enlighten me how to aim to have this kind of accuracy, defeating the randomness of CS GO?

Comment: whilst using the scout and jumping, when at the height of your jump, the scout is 100% accurate.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you're not moving (as in not pressing w, s, a, or d) the scout is relatively accurate while you're falling (only when falling, while jumping your accuracy is not good)

example:

Answer (score 0):

You can't. They're lucky I guess. The only jump headshots you can make while aiming on someones head is with a scout. When you jump with a scout, it hits exactly where you aim (only jump. Don't move forward, backwards, left or right).

Answer (score 0):

Depends on where you aim and luck.
But if you meant by some people jumping and headshoting an enemy very easily with 1 shot, I believe those people are cheating.